# C# / inherit methods and properties from COM Reference (SolidWorks API)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, inheritance, solidworks

I am working with the SolidWorks API with C#.

(see http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapiprogguide/GettingStarted/Understanding_the_SolidWorks_API_Class_Hierarchy.htm?id=260f4593adf14e1198dc3fa3b4711bd7)

This is incorporated into Visual Studio by adding a series of COM References to the project.  The API comes with a variety of classes.  I'd like to create a sub-class that adds methods to the classes that come with the API in order to add functionality to the superclasses.

The code below shows a trivial example without the API.  It, of course, works just fine.

```
public class x
{
    public double a;
}

public class y : x
{
    public double b;

    public void setAandB(double aa, double bb)
    {
        this.a = aa;
        this.b = bb;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of my attempt to add a method using a sub-class.  The superclass is **SketchPoint**.

```
public class SketchPointWriter : SketchPoint
{

    public void writeXML(XmlWriter writer, string nameElement)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(nameElement);
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(((SketchPoint)this).X * 1000.0) + ", ");
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(((SketchPoint)this).Y * 1000.0) + ", ");
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(((SketchPoint)this).Z * 1000.0));
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

**SketchPoint** from the API does not have the ability to write itself to an XML file.  So, I want to add this functionality to the class by creating a sub-class, inheriting all the superclass's properties and methods, and then add my new method.

Please note the explicit type casting of **this**.  Without this type casting, Visual Studio is not aware that **.X** is a property of **this**.  In and of itself, I find this puzzling, so I resolved it with some heavy type casting.

Even with this type casting, it won't compile because Visual Studio throws errors because I have not explicitly created each and every method:
*'ExportHOE.SketchPointWriter' does not implement interface member 'SldWorks.ISketchPoint.Type'*

This creates a conundrum in my mind.  What is the point of inheritance if I need to rewrite all the methods?  The API is not source code, it is a DLL (?) so I don't have access to the source.

So, the question is:

1. Is my code correct and the API is implemented in a way that doesn't really allow for inheritance of their own objects (it is actually an interface that does not allow for inheritance)?
2. Is my code written poorly and re-writing the code will enable inheritance of properties and methods?
3. Is it impossible to tell and therefore, I should really just give up and code another solution?
4. Is there a clever work-around that is not as ideal as native C#, but creates the same functionality?

Comment: COM does not support implementation inheritance, only interface inheritance.  It can be emulated with delegation.  What you are trying to do doesn't in general make much sense, you'd never get Solidworks to create an instance of your SketchPointWriter class or make a call to a writeXML() method, it doesn't know beans about them.  Use encapsulation instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Solidworks documentation you referenced](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapiprogguide/GettingStarted/Understanding_the_SolidWorks_API_Class_Hierarchy.htm?id=260f4593adf14e1198dc3fa3b4711bd7), SolidWorks provides a COM-based API. COM (the Component Object Model) is built around **interface** inheritance and provides no intrinsic support for the **implementation** inheritance you appear to be looking for. In fact, COM **by design** prevents you from accessing the innards of the various objects in any manner other than via the declared interfaces. (See [The Component Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [COM Objects and Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN for a brief overview of what COM is and is not.)

So, yes, their API is implemented in a way which does not support inheriting the implementation of their objects. OTOH, it sounds like your goal is to use C# to write additional functionality for Solidworks-provided objects while relying only on their public interfaces. For that purpose, your best bet would be to create [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), along the lines of:

```
public static class SolidWorksExtensions
{
    public static void writeXml(this SketchPoint point, 
        XmlWriter writer, string nameElement)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(nameElement);
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(point.X * 1000.0) + ", ");
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(point.Y * 1000.0) + ", ");
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(point.Z * 1000.0));
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Decorator Pattern for this matter:

```
public class SketchPointWriter
{
   private SketchPoint _sketchPoint;

   public SketchPointWriter(SketchPoint sketchPoint)
   {
       _sketchPoint = sketchPoint;
   }

   public void writeXml(XmlWriter writer, string nameElement)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(nameElement);
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(_sketchPoint.X * 1000.0) + ", ");
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(_sketchPoint.Y * 1000.0) + ", ");
        writer.WriteString(Convert.ToString(_sketchPoint.Z * 1000.0));
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```